# How do I make namespaces visible to Assembly Explorers?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, rider

I am using the Rider IDE with mono & mono-msbuild on Linux, for reference.

As I was checking out the assembly explorer, I noticed that some DLLs, including mine, did not expse their namespaces, while some did, and would like to know why. I looked around on Google, but could not find any relevant posts.

[Here is my csproj file](https://pastiebin.com/6045062507001)

[AssemblyInfo.cs](https://pastiebin.com/604506c0546b5)

An example of what I am talking about
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgKib.png)

If any .NET veteran knows the solution, it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Sounds like a bug of Rider.

Comment: Yeap, this one: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-57382

Comment: Well that sucks. Guess i'll just have to wait until .NET 5.x is supported in the assembly viewer. Until then, I'll use ILSpy